# Advice - Redis or RabbitMQ PubSub - Auction service

Tags: redis, rabbitmq

For a new auction system I am looking for which technology is the best for me.

When there is a new bid, I want to notify the listening users on the auction page. This is something for a pubsub technique, i presume.

First I did take a look at RabbitMQ, and I think this is a good way to build this. But it means I have an extra single point of failure.

So now I am leaning towards Redis PubSub. I know it has disadvantages, because when an user is not listening it won't re-send messages. But that is not a problem. When a user sign in it has all the current bids, and then only want updates. I don't plan to create a chat with a history.

What can you advice? Are there anymore disadvantages to use Redis for this? How about the stability? When a bid occurs, and I want to send the newest price to all listening users, how certain am I everyone gets the message?

Does anyone have experience with this situation?

Thanks

Comment: What's the technology? HTML/JS, native App?

Comment: PHP 7.0 / MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

Pro: redis is much simpler than RabbitMQ to set up.

Cons: there is [no guarantee of delivery with Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675394/redis-publish-subscribe-is-redis-guaranteed-to-deliver-the-message-even-under-m).

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that by "page" you mean standard HTML page with PHP on backend. If yes, then your main problem is not "should I use Redis or RabbitMQ", because you cannot make direct connection between your user browser and Redis or RabbitMQ.

First you have two answer to yourself, how will you provide updates for the page:

- by regular ajax requests asking "is there any new for me"
- by using some implementation of websocket

and after selecting answer, you will see that pub/sub mechanism has any use at all in your situation.

Comment: I am sorry, but ofcourse I have node.js and socket.io, and will make use of websockets